# Python in Visual Studio - 'CoreCompile' error

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 with Python support and Python 3.5 64bit. I want to check how VS cooperate with Python for learning purpose.

I have tried to run simply program

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

result = add(3,4)
print(result)
```

When I run [F5] or build [Ctrl + Shift + F5] I get such error:

> Error MSB4057: The target "CoreCompile" does not exist in the project.

I think everything is configured well. I can use python console in VS. Environment is visible in Solution Explorer. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

- Open your project in a text editor.
- Find and uncomment the following lines `<!--<Target Name="CoreCompile" />-->`

Hopefully it should work for you.